# Where to get GRASS module r3.out.vtk?

Tags: grass-gis

I'm looking for the GRASS module r3.out.vtk. It's featured on the GRASS GIS manual :
http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r3.out.vtk.html

But it's nowhere to be found, and neither are r.out.vtk and v.out.vtk. All I could find is a dead link on this web page : 
http://osdir.com/ml/grass-development-gis/2005-06/msg00287.html

Answer (score 4):

These are GRASS GIS standard commands:

[r3.out.vtk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r3.out.vtk.html):

[image]

[r.out.vtk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.vtk.html):

[image]

[v.out.vtk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.out.vtk.html):

[image]